# How to find average number of occurences (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

Table of surnames in a reference list and I need to find the average number of times a surname appears in the list,
I have used the command:

```
SELECT column5, COUNT(*)
FROM table1
GROUP BY column5
```

to get a list of occurrences but there are over 800 in my database so I can manually find an average
So some authors have published 9 books, some only 1, how do I find the average of this?

Comment: please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

this is a great place to start  http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  You seem confused about tables and databases.  You mention "authors" and "books", but your example query does not reference anything like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the "average number of books per author", you must select the total number of books divided by the total number of authors:

```
SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) AS DECIMAL) / COUNT(DISTINCT column5)
FROM table1;
```

Note: I used the `CAST ... AS DECIMAL` syntax to make the result show as a decimal instead of being truncated to an integer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the AVG function try this  eg:

```
SELECT column5, COUNT(*), avg(column5) 
FROM table1
GROUP BY column5
```

Answer (score 1):

It is allowed to compose (i.e. nest) aggregate functions, so why not simply this:

```
SELECT AVG(COUNT(*)) average_occurrences
FROM table1
GROUP BY column5
```